# "I'd done..." vs "I had done..."

Tags: contractions, common-word

Is the former less common for native English speakers because it kinda sound like *I done*? I'm basing this assumption on [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I'd%20done%2CI%20had%20done&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20%27d%20done%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20had%20done%3B%2Cc0). But I may be wrong.

Example sentences:

> Plus, I was ashamed to admit, I'd done nothing for the club so far.
>
> Plus, I was ashamed to admit, I had done nothing for the club so far.

Comment: There is a slight difference in the sound (basically duration and emphasis), and I'd doubt anybody thinks about it much.

Comment: In conversational English, "I'd done" is significantly more common than "I had done".

Comment: Ngram is not a reliable source for speech trend, it is a record of written texts. Whether people say "I'd done it earlier" more or less frequently than "I had done it earlier" would be very difficult to assess or prove. However, the auxiliary  *had* is  sometimes stressed to emphasize the time difference between *then* and *now*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'd done* is the contracted form of *I had done*, and it is used in spoken English more often, since the shorter forms are usually the feature of the spoken language (the economy principle in language). Of course they are also pronounced differently.

Here is a nice reference: http://web.stanford.edu/~bresnan/contraction.pdf

Answer (score 2):

"I'd done" would be the most common way to phrase that in casual speech.  However, if you were writing something formal it would be more common to write, "I had done".